# Craft Commerce multisite mail origin

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, emails

I have a multisite setup where 2 sites can make orders on the same commerce, but I would like to have dynamic mail settings (domain name, origin, api keys, etc) based on the site of the order.

Do you know if it's feasable ? Intercepting a mail event maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Craft Commerce's events, you can do pretty much anything to the emails before they are sent.

Recently, the good folks at P&T added an event code generator system to their documentation page for events:

https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/extend/events.html

As a rough sketch, you can set up en event listener in your plugin/modules init method, like this:

```php
    public function init(): void
    {

        parent::init();
        self::$instance = $this;

        $this->_setPluginComponents();

        Event::on(Emails::class, Emails::EVENT_BEFORE_SEND_MAIL, static function(MailEvent $e) {
            modify_email_function($e);
        });
    }
```

And then

```php
   public function modify_email_function(MailEvent $event): void
    {
        $order = $event->order;
        $orderHistory = $event->orderHistory;
        $commerceEmail = $event->commerceEmail;
        
        ...your code here, whatever you like really.

   }
```

One thing to factor in to your thinking is quite how/when this function will be called - as Commerce's emails are generally sent via a queue job, which has some implications as to what is available to your code at that time (e.g. if you're using a queue runner that causes the queue jobs to be, in effect, run from the console, there will not be a valid user at that time, just as an example).

(There is a corresponding `EVENT_AFTER_SEND_EMAIL` of course, if you you need to set anything back etc.)

Docs for these events:

https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/extend/events.html#beforesendemail

https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/extend/events.html#aftersendemail

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! Do you have any idea how I could alter the mailer configuration from there ? Like changing mailgun's config

Comment: Not immediately, but I'd first look at Craft's config service - https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-config.html (e.g get config from file) - and then the mail adaptors all extend from: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-mail-transportadapters-basetransportadapter.html